# 'AdaptiveCard' does not contain a definition for 'FromJson'--Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I have tried creating an adaptive card, parsing it from json. As mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/create/libraries/net#example-parse-from-json, I have installed AdaptiveCards package and tried using that function, but it throws a error like 'AdaptiveCard' does not contain a definition for 'FromJson'.

Answer (score 4):

As there is a Breaking changes from v0.5:

> Package renamed from Microsoft.AdaptiveCards to AdaptiveCards

It seems that you have installed `Microsoft.AdaptiveCards` but `AdaptiveCards`.

To install `AdaptiveCards`, please mark `Include prerelease` checkbox in NuGet package manager:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the documentation is outdated. The class is named AdaptiveCard now, without the last 's'.

So instead of:

```
var parseResult = AdaptiveCards.FromJson(card);
```

Use:

```
var parseResult = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(card);
```

Comment: As of today, the Card editor in App Studio also has the old documentation so the sample code generated still says "AdaptiveCards"