# Not able to get this AdaptiveCard.FromJson

Tags: c#

FromJson Method is missing from AdaptiveCard.

```
var card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson("EmployeeCard.json", myEmployee);
```

Not able to get "FromJson"

My requirement is simply to design the card template in the c# code and pass the data to template and finally to display in browser.

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068862/adaptivecard-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-fromjson-microsoft-bot-frame  Ithink you have some Nuget package problem